# TCPDF renders no PNG Image

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

When i am using [`TCPDF`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html) to create a PDF, everything works fine with `.jpg` images. But when ill try to use an `.png` image, no image is shown, just blank white space. There is no error in any log, and the path for the image is correct.

So if ill use:

```php
$pdf->Image($path.$imageURL, 15, 15, 178, 129, 'JPG', '', '');
```

Everything is fine, the image is there as expected. But with:

```php
$pdf->Image($path.$imageURL, 15, 15, 178, 129, 'PNG', '', '');
```

where `$imageURL` is an `PNG` image, there is no image in my PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can You add `$path.$imageURL` var_dump? And try change `$type` param to `''`, `Image` can work without hard format define.

Comment: I've rendered thousands of PNG files and never had a problem with TCPDF, so I'm guessing its the file. Is there any transparency in the image? Also, is the problem with all PNG images (eg. any random image from the Internet) or only with certain images that you are creating yourself?

Comment: In this special case its just an screenshot from iOS - so there should be no transparency. But thanks, i will try another image too. When ill var_dump the path everything is correct - the file exists on the path. So ill think it should really be a problem with the image itself.

Answer (score 2):

This page with a lot of [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) is very good to start TCPDF

On the example 42 ([PHP](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_042.phps) -> [PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_042.pdf)), they use that :

```
$pdf->Image('images/image_with_alpha.png', 50, 50, 100, '', '', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', false, 300);
```

The doesn't set 'PNG'. I let you try this.